# Interpretation of probability in Statistical Mechanics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability, partition-function, quantum-statistics

In statistical mechanics, in particular the canonical ensemble, the probability of the system to have a particular state is given by : $$P_i=\frac{e^{-\beta E}}{Z}$$

Here $Z$ is the partition function of this system. My question is, how do we interpret this probability ?

Does it mean, that if we measure the system, there is a $P_i$ chance that the system would have this energy $E$ ?

Suppose our system has a single particle. In that case $P_i$ can be interpreted as the probability of that particle to be in that particular state. Then if we had many particles in this system, we could interpret $P_i$ as the ratio of the number of particles in the $E$ state, and all the particles in the system.

According to wikipedia :

> The Boltzmann distribution is often used to describe the distribution
> of particles, such as atoms or molecules, over bound states accessible
> to them. If we have a system consisting of many particles, the
> probability of a particle being in state $i$ is practically the
> probability that, if we pick a random particle from that system and
> check what state it is in, we will find it is in state $i$. This
> probability is equal to the number of particles in state $i$ divided by
> the total number of particles in the system, that is the fraction of
> particles that occupy state $i$.

But now suppose, I have a system consisting of many particles, and the probability of the system being in a particular state is still given by the same formula. However, each state is now built using combinations of different particles in different states. We are no longer talking about single particles, we are talking about the system as a whole.

Suppose I want to find the probability that $x_i$ particles are in the $E$ single particle state i.e. all of them are in the same single particle state. My question is, how to interpret this in a way similar to how wikipedia interpreted the single particle probabilities :

Will it go something like : probability that $x_i$ particles are in the $E$ state, is the same thing as picking up $x_i$ particles and random, and checking the probability of all of them being in the same state $E$ ?

However this creates a slight issue.

Suppose, we found out that out of a 100 particles, the probability of a single particle being in the $E$ state is $0.2$. We can conclude that there must be $20$ particles in the system with energy $E$.

Then suppose, I ask, what is the probability of the state, in which $100$ particles have the same energy $E$. This is given by some $p_i^{100}$. This would give me some number. However, this doesn't make sense to me.

Didn't we already establish that there are $20$  particles with energy $E$ ? Doesn't this already mean that the probability of $100$ particles being in the same energy state is $0$ i.e. impossible ?

If the probability of a single particle having $E$ energy is $0.2$ and there are $100$ particles in all, then the number of particles with energy $E$ must $20$. But this would mean, the probability of all the particles having the same energy must be $0$, since only $20$ particles have that energy.

There seems to be something wrong about my reasoning, and something subtle that I'm not being able to understand.

What am I missing ?

Comment: "Suppose, we found out that out of a 100 particles, the probability of a single particle being in the E state is 0.2. We can conclude that there must be 20 particles in the system with energy E." The quantity you are describing here is *expectation value*. We can conclude that we **expect** 20 particles to have energy E, but since it is not certain (the probability is not 1 for this to happen) we cannot say for certain.

Comment: Analogy: if you roll a die, the probability of getting a 5 is 1/6. If you roll 6 dice, can you then conclude that one of them **must** be a 5? I think you agree that the answer is no.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer can we say that the probability of $20$ particles to have energy $E$ is more than the probability of $m\ne 20$ particles to have energy E. Is this the most probable value ?

Comment: That depends. If all particles were indistinguishable and independent, there would be a binomial (two different single-particle energies) or more generally multinomial distribution of the probabilities. But that is not what we normally do in statistical mechanics. In what we call the microcanonical ensemble, for instance, we assume that **all microstates of the full system are equally probable**. In that case, the most probable total energy E is simply the one that has the largest number of corresponding microstates.